# Drawing OpenGL ES 2.0 Line with onTouch Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I've downloaded and run the opengl sample from android. now, i try to make a line with opengl es 2.0 while user is moving their finger. so far this is what i've done:

on my GlSurfaceView class onTouchEvent method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();

            mPreviousX = x;
            mPreviousY = y;

            // Save the ID of this pointer
            mActivePointerId = e.getPointerId(0);

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            final int pointerIndex = e.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = e.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = e.getY(pointerIndex);

            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {

                mRenderer.setLineCoordinates(mPreviousX, mPreviousY, x, y);
                requestRender();
            }

            mPreviousX = x;
            mPreviousY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = e.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mPreviousX = e.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mPreviousY = e.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = e.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

on my renderer class:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Draw background color
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set GL_MODELVIEW transformation mode
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();   // reset the matrix to its default state

    // When using GL_MODELVIEW, you must set the view point
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    gl.glScalef(factor, factor, 0.0f);

    // Draw triangle
    mTriangle.draw(gl);
    mLine.draw(gl);
}
```

function inside renderer class to change coordinates:

```
public void setLineCoordinates(float mPreviousX
        , float mPreviousY, float x, float y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    lineCoords[0] = (float) (mPreviousX * 2.0 / WIDTH - 1.0);
    lineCoords[1] = (float) (mPreviousY * -2.0 / HEIGHT + 1.0);
    lineCoords[2] = 0.0f;
    lineCoords[3] = (float) (x * 2.0 / WIDTH - 1.0);
    lineCoords[4] = (float) (y * -2.0 / HEIGHT + 1.0);
    lineCoords[5] = 0.0f;

}
```

when i move my finger, there's no line, just a moving piece of tiny line...
how can i draw the whole line and keep the line drawing while i keep moving my finger? also start new line when i touch down the screen again.

**UPDATED**

Thanks for @Gil Moshayof i can draw line now with my version like this

```
public void setLineCoordinates(float mPreviousX
        , float mPreviousY, float x, float y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    float lineCoords[] = new float[6];
    lineCoords[0] = (float) (mPreviousX * 2.0 / WIDTH - 1.0);
    lineCoords[1] = (float) (mPreviousY * -2.0 / HEIGHT + 1.0);
    lineCoords[2] = 0.0f;
    lineCoords[3] = (float) (x * 2.0 / WIDTH - 1.0);
    lineCoords[4] = (float) (y * -2.0 / HEIGHT + 1.0);
    lineCoords[5] = 0.0f;

    bufferOfArrays.add(new Line(lineCoords));

    if(isFirst) {
        isFirst = false;
        listOfArrays.addAll(bufferOfArrays);
        view.requestRender();
    }

}

public void setFirst(boolean isFirst) {
    this.isFirst = isFirst;
}
```

and then:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //... color, matrix, look at etc..

    // Draw triangle
    //mTriangle.draw(gl);
    //TODO mLine.draw(gl);

    for(Line line : listOfArrays) {
        line.draw(gl);
    }
    isFirst = true;

}
```

but my app starts to slow down while moving my finger, still have no idea what's happening

Comment: You have to keep a list of all your line segments, and draw all of them in `onDrawFrame()`. Right now you're only drawing the last line, which is replaced every time you process input.

Comment: did you successfully complete it,please give me a link to download the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're always setting mPreviousX & mPreviousY on every move. Actually, the problem starts with the name you chose for these parameters. A better name would be mLineStartX/Y.

Set mLineStartX/Y on the touch down event, then update the x/y on every move and don't change the mLineStartX/Y.

As for adding multiple lines, you'll need to implement a bit more logic. You'll need to maintain an array list of some class you define which has 2 point (2xPointFs). The moment the user lifts his finger (touch up / touch cancel), create a new class with the 2 points, and on your render method, make sure you go over all such lines and render them.

Comment: can i use this to accomplish my free draw path? actually i'm not intended to make a straight line but mostly like path that would draw my finger's track while i'm moving my finger.

Comment: Then you should go according to the 2nd part I wrote. Every time you move, you need to add 2 points (representing a line) into a list. Then, when you draw, you need to generate (or generate prior to this) a list of vertex buffers which represent all these line segments. Essentially, you should have a list of "Lines", where touch down creates a new instance, and touch up (or cancel) adds the new instance into a list.

Comment: Thanks your answer is very useful! i can draw freeform lines now but the system seems getting slower